# Liferay 6.2: Where is the content used on "/home"-page physically saved?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I basically googled for a few hours now but it seems like I can't find the right tags to come to an answer.

I want to know where the content that is shown on the "/home"-page of my Liferay portal is saved. My problem is that the Document and Media-Portlet I want to use is shown as "already in use" but not showing up anywhere on the page. Now I have to delete the portlet from the /home-page at its physical location.

Any ideas where to find it?

TIA

Comment: Please mark show edit control, portlet should be visible. There may be chance that its not visible due to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check layout table for details that what all portlets are placed on particular page.

In typeSettings column, it stores portlet ids per column.

NOTE:Please mark show edit control, portlet should be visible. There may be chance that its not visible due to that.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that the page glitched and thought the portlet was active although I deleted it.
I deleted the /home-page and created a new one and fixed it that way. Seems like Liferay 6.2 isn't that stable so this happens sometimes.

Comment: Maybe you've got this portlet embedded on the page. Go to manage pages and select the page. On the right menu, select the embedd portlets and look if the portlet is located there.